# Changing a function to also work for negative values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, math, time

I have a function inside my app that takes a value and puts it out in a special way. It is there to calculate a value to be the same value but split in "hours : minutes".

I need the function to also work for negative values - something like an if check inside the function to check if the entered time is negative and then to change the calculation/output.

Here is the function its pretty straight forward:

```
   const calcSingle = time => {        
      // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
      let hour = Math.floor(time / 60);
      let minutes = time % 60;

      hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

      return hour + ":" + minutes;
  };
```

If I call this on for example:

`calcSingle(200)` I get back "03:20" which is the correct value.

However if I try `calcSingle(-200)` I get: "0-4:0-20" which obviously is wrong because it should be the same value but with a minus so this => "-03:20".

```js
const calcSingle = time => {
  // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
  let hour = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let minutes = time % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  return hour + ":" + minutes;
};
console.log(
  calcSingle(200)
)


console.log(
  calcSingle(-200)
)
```

Edit: Thanks for all the responses from all of you guys I will use math.abs it solves my problem! Great help guys - have a good day!

Comment: out of curiousity, why does it need to work with negative numbers? Beyond that, why not just use `Math.abs` around the `time` variable in the first line?

Comment: you are passing time as negative so your calculation of hour and minutes are in negative when concat 0 to hour or minutes then "0" + -hour will hive 0-hour:0-minute

Comment: @Jhecht because I need to display how many hours our workers do and they can have negative hours for a month :)

Comment: How do you work negative hours???

Comment: @Jhecht if you have to get 150hours in a month lets say but you only work 145 hours than you have -05:00 in the next month to start with

Comment: I'm assuming that has something to do with contract obligations because otherwise it makes no sense to me how someone could work negative hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add check at beginning and call same function changing sign.

```
  if (time < 0) {
    return `-${calcSingle(Math.abs(time))}`;
  }
```

Like this

```js
const calcSingle = time => {
  if (time < 0) {
    return `-${calcSingle(Math.abs(time))}`;
  }

  // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
  let hour = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let minutes = time % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  return hour + ":" + minutes;
};

console.log(calcSingle(200));
console.log(calcSingle(-200));
```

Comment: That is actually nice

Comment: Im think im gonna go with this one actually because its just 2 lines more code and does what I want can u explain how the "-" is set by this automatically?

Comment: @yesIamFaded, Actually am prepending '-' to result using template string. (return `-${calcSingle(Math.abs(time))}`) when applicable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `Math.abs()` will solve your problem:

```js
const calcSingle = time => {     
  let isNegative = time < 0;
  let _time = Math.abs(time);
  // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
  let hour = Math.floor(_time / 60);
  let minutes = _time % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  return (isNegative ? '-':'') + hour + ":" + minutes;
};


console.log(
  calcSingle(200)
)


console.log(
  calcSingle(-200)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest version

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const calcSingle = time => {
  let _time = Math.abs(time);
  let hour = pad(Math.floor(_time / 60));
  let minutes = pad(_time % 60);
  return (time < 0 ? '-' : '') + hour + ":" + minutes;
};

console.log(
  calcSingle(200)
)
console.log(
  calcSingle(-200)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to store the value and append the minus at the end of result

```js
calcSingle = time => {
  var bIsNegative = false;
  if (time < 0) {
    bIsNegative = true;
  }
  time = Math.abs(time);
  // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
  let hour = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let minutes = time % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  return bIsNegative ? "-" + (hour + ":" + minutes) : hour + ":" + minutes;
};
console.log(
  calcSingle(200)
)
console.log(
  calcSingle(-200)
)
```

Comment: I'd personally rewrite it so that `bIsNegative` was an empty string originally and the `-` otherwise, so that the last line could be rewritten ` return bIsNegative + hour + ":" + minutes`

Comment: `abs`is supposed to be `Math.abs`

Answer (score 0):

`Math.abs` can be used.
[Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

```js
const calcSingle = time => {
  // insert a if check somewhere here to check for time and if its negative
  let _time = Math.abs(time);
  let hour = Math.floor(_time / 60);
  let minutes = _time % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  return (time < 0 ? '-' : '') + hour + ":" + minutes;
};
console.log(calcSingle(200), calcSingle(-200));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Math.abs()` to get the absolute value of `time`. You can then check in your return statement whether your initial time is less than 0 (therefore a negative number) and use that to return either a positive or negative time.

You could use the following code:

```
const calcSingle = time => {
  const absTime = Math.abs(time);
  let hour = Math.floor(absTime / 60);
  let minutes = absTime % 60;

  hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

  return `${time < 0 ? "-" : ""}${hour}:${minutes}`;
};
```

Comment: I think we have all come to the same conclusion at least 10 minutes ago ;)